# ArrayList saved to textfile

Tags: java, arraylist, text-files

I want to save the contents of my arraylist to a textfile. What I have so far is shown below, however instead of adding    x.format("%s%s", "100", "control1");    to the textfile, I want to add objects from an arraylist, how do I go about this?

```
import java.util.*;

public class createfile
{
    ArrayList<String> control = new ArrayList<String>();

    private Formatter x;

    public void openFile()
    {
        try {
            x = new Formatter("ControlLog.txt");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: Your file has not been created");
        }
    }

    public void addRecords()
    {
        x.format("%s%s", "100", "control1");
    }

    public void closeFile()
    {
        x.close();
    }
}

public class complete
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        createfile g = new createfile();
        g.openFile();
        g.addRecords();
        g.closeFile();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need first to create an ArrayList. Then you'll iterate on the ArrayList elements (maybe using a for block) and for each element, you'll format it and print this formatted string into a filewriter.

Comment: Can I ask what is it for?

Comment: Yes, I have created an arrayList as shown above. The elements are dependent on user input so obviously I cant add that in now. I just want to know how to write the arrayList to the textfile

Comment: Its for a project im trying, so I can understand java better. Im a newbie!

Answer (score 0):

Both ArrayList and String implement [Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html).  Since you have an ArrayList of string you can write it to the file like this:

```
 FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("path/to/file");
 ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
 out.writeObject(myArrayList);  //Where my array list is the one you created
 out.close();
```

[Here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-an-object-to-file-in-java/)  is a really good tutorial that shows you how to write java objects to a file.

The written objects can be read back from the file in a similar way.

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("path/to/file");
ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(in);
myArrayList = (ArrayList<String>) is.readObject(); //Note that you will get an unchecked warning here
is.close()
```

[Here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-an-object-from-file-in-java/) is a tutorial on how to read objects back from a file.